# Does quantum mechanics invalidate causality and determinism?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, causality, determinism

The conductors of [this experiment](https://science.slashdot.org/story/18/09/15/1641233/quantum-experiment-confirms-causality-is-fuzzy) claim that causality is broken or at least made fuzzy by quantum mechanics.  Is this really the case?

Comment: I think that if you spelled out in more detail what the experiment is and what kind of argument it is making, then you could ask the question again and it would not be mistaken for a repeat of an existing question.

Comment: If it's a news article on quantum physics, it automatically belongs in the trash. :) Physicists and philosophers of physics have a hard time as it is in interpreting QM, so other people writing about it will not report on things accurately, especially considering there is a pressure for attention and clickbait.